# Inheritance in std::map with base class as value

Tags: c++, inheritance, dictionary, stl

Here is a code:

```
class Base {
    public:
        long index;
};
class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        bool value;
};

void call(map<char *, Base *> *base) {
    map<char *, Base *>::iterator it = base->begin();
    cout << it->second->index << endl;
}
void test(void) {
    map<char *, Derived *> *d = new map<char *, Derived *>;

    call(d);
}
```

Compiler alerts an error:

```
error C2664: 'call' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> *' to 'std::map<_Kty,_Ty> *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=char *,
1>            _Ty=Derived *
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            _Kty=char *,
1>            _Ty=Base *
1>        ]
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

I understand why this error is happened.
I do not understand how to make it work. What kind of cast and how to use it?

**UPD**

I'm sorry for imprecision, let me explain more details.
I have two sets of data represented by ClassA and ClassB.
Both of these classes have one common member - an "index", for example.
Both sets are wrapped into a maps (special thanks to Rob for a significant correction with char*):

```
std::map<char, ClassA>
std::map<char, ClassB>
```

Sometime I need to iterate over both maps to get a value of a common member "index".
I'm trying to avoid code duplication and make just one function to iterate over both maps.

I thought I may extract a superclass with a common member and make a function with parameter like this one:

```
std::map<char, SuperClassAB>
```

or

```
std::map<char, SuperClassAB>::iterator
```

But looks like it's a bad idea.

**UPD2**

One smart guy gave me the solution:

```
template <class T>
void call(map<char, T> *base) {
    map<char, T>::iterator it = base->begin();
    cout << it->second->index << endl;
}
void test(void) {
    map<char, Derived *> d;
    call(&d);
}
```

Comment: A `map<char*, Derived*>` is unrelated to a `map<char*, Base*>`, and rightly so. Otherwise, you could have the same problems as with `Base**` and `Derived**`.

Comment: (Side remark: The dynamic allocation is unnecessary here. Consider using just `map<char*, Derived*> d;`. It's also error-prone to use owning raw pointers inside Standard Library containers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one seemed to suggest this yet, but you could also make `call` a function template.

```
    template <class Type>
    void call(const std::map<char*,Type*> & base)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Type>::value,
                      "Function is only callable with maps "
                      "whose mapped_type is derived from Base");
        /* More stuff */
    }
```

This way the function is callable with `Base`, `Derived` and anything else that derives from `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to "operate" in some way on the derived class, create a virtual method on the base class and override it to get the specific behavior you want:

```
class Base
{
public:
   long index;
   virtual void doSomething()
   {
      // Do something with index
      cout << index << endl;
   }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   bool value;

   virtual void doSomething()
   {
      // Do something with value
      cout << value << endl;
   }
};

// NOTE:  I removed the pointer and made it a ref.
// NOTE:  I made it "const" because you probably don't want to alter the
// map.  If you do...
void call(const map<char *, Base *>& base)
{
   map<char *, Base *>::const_iterator it = base.begin();
   //   cout << it->second->index << endl;
   it->second->doSomething();
}

void test(void)
{
   map<char *, Base *> d;
   // Push some members into d...I didn't, but you should
   // if you want call(...) to be meaningful.
   call(d);
}
```

Was this helpful?

Comment: `map<char *, Base *>::iterator it = base->begin();` will not work for a `map<..> const&`. You'll have to use a `const_iterator`.

Comment: That's what I get for doing in place edits instead of sticking it in the compiler and making sure...doh!  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast these types.  `map<char*,Base*>` and `map<char*,Derived*>` are as different as `string` and `float`.

Simplest thing to do is within `test()` simply populate a `map<char*,Base*>` and call `call` with that.  Provide `virtual` methods in `Base` (possibly pure `virtual`), and implement those functions in `Derived`.

You could attempt to `transform` a `map<char*,Derived*>` from a `map<char*,Base*>`, but in order to do so your functor would need to either:

1. Absolutely *know* that the `Base*` actually points to a `Derived` object, and use `static_cast`.
2. Make `Base` polymorphic (usually by implementing a `virtual` destructor), and use `dynamic_cast`

Comment: I'm not sure if polymorphism (as in: different behaviour depending on the dynamic type) is actually necessary here, the OP's `call` function only uses a member of the base class.

Comment: @DyP:  It's necessary in order to use `dynamic_cast` in this manner.  Whether or not using `dynamic_cast` is necessary depends on OP's design.

Comment: Umm.. I don't see any necessity for a cast in the OP's code. There's `it->second->index`, which accesses a member of the *base* class, and I can't see any accesses to members of derived classes. Of course, when *initially* using a `map<char*,Base*>` (with owning `Base*`), you need polymorphism again.

Comment: @DyP:  OP's posted code might not reflect the actual use case completely.  I don't know that the cast is necesarry; I'm simply offering it up as a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need your container to store base class pointers instead of derived class pointers.

E.g.`map<char *, Base *> *d;`.

Thereafter, you should populate the map with elements of whatever derived types you want. E.g.

```
char keyA = 'A';
char keyB = 'B';
(*d)[&keyA] = new Derived();
(*d)[&keyB] = new AnotherDerived();
```

Would that work in your instance?

As an aside, why are you using `char *` as the key seems like an odd choice.

Comment: You may also want to use a shared_ptr or similar to manage the ownership and lifespan of the Derived pointers in your map. Otherwise they'll need to be manually cleaned up later.

Comment: @DyP Thanks. I'll fix it up. Serves me right for compiling snippets of code without warnings as errors ;)

Comment: Rob, "char*" is my mistake with preparing example, thanks for remark.