# C++ How best to model containers with similar data

Tags: c++, oop

I'm new to OOP/C++ and am struggling with a seemingly simple problem.
I have a class with some data and a derived class with some additional data. I want objects of these classes to be in containers (specifically map) and be able to call functions which can accept either value_type. 
I posted the following question (thx for answers) which was a first attempt but am concerned that it's overly complicated (e.g. requires lots of templated functions, dynamic casts (see first link answer below), posts saying not to store raw pointers in containers, etc)

[Can I pass a reference to a map where the data is a pointer to a derived class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40227621/can-i-pass-a-reference-to-a-map-where-the-data-is-a-pointer-to-a-derived-class)

Related:
[Inheritance in std::map with base class as value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20761457/inheritance-in-stdmap-with-base-class-as-value)

Another approach I'm looking at is to have different container wrappers as shown below. This feels terribly clumsy - e.g. I really don't want to have to write wrappers for methods like 'insert'.
The example shows a container of one_coord value_type and another container of two_coord value_type.
Any suggestions on how to model this appreciated.

```
#include <map>

// has a single coordinate value
class one_coord {

private:
  int coord_a_;

};

// has two coordinate values
class two_coord : public one_coord {
private:
  int coord_b_;
};

// a container with one_coord objects
class one_coord_map {

public:
  typedef one_coord value_type;
  // yuck:
  void insert(int k, value_type& v) { m_.insert(std::pair<int, value_type>(k, v) ); }
    // etc...
private:
  typedef std::map<int, value_type> pair_type;
    pair_type m_;

};

// a container with two_coord objects
class two_coord_map {

public:
  typedef two_coord value_type;
    // insert etc ??? 
private:
  typedef std::map<int, two_coord> pair_type;
  pair_type m_;

};

int main() {

  one_coord_map one_cm; 
  two_coord_map two_cm; 

  one_coord oc;

  one_cm.insert(0, oc); // just for example

  return 0;
}
```

The latest coord_map is as follows, but it can't be right to have to redo insert, erase, etc.

```
  template <typename T>
  class coord_map {
  public:
    typedef T value_type;
    void insert(int k, value_type& v) { m_.insert(std::pair<int, value_type>(k, v) ); }
    // etc...
  private:
    typedef std::map<int, value_type> pair_type;
    pair_type m_;
  };
```

Comment: Use `std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<one_coord>>` to avoid the slicing problem.

Comment: These are two different types, why can't you just have two separate maps?

Comment: e.g. coord_a_ is tightly linked to coord_b_ but coord_b_ isn't always required.

Comment: Then what about using a `std::vector` with either one or two elements?

Comment: Or just use `two_coord` and ignore the second coord unless required?

Comment: That's one alternative but in the actual case I have there will be many more datum which would be unused and end up wasting memory.

Comment: With a *polymorphic* solution you will have to store pointers to everything. That is probably going to cost you more memory and more *time to access* than simply storing one redundant integer *by value*.